# How to add URL fragment HtmlOutcomeTargetLink?

Tags: jsf-2, hyperlink, fragment-identifier

I would like to add an URL fragment `#top` to a `HtmlOutcomeTargetLink`, but cant figure out how. For an `HtmlOutputLink` I just use the following:

```
      HtmlOutputLink link = new HtmlOutputLink();
      String urlWithFragment = url + "#top";
      link.setValue(urlWithFragment);
```

How to acomplish this for a `HtmlOutcomeTargetLink`?

Unfortunately the following does not work:

```
      HtmlOutcomeTargetLink link = new HtmlOutcomeTargetLink();
      String urlWithFragment = context.getViewRoot().getViewId() + "#top";
      link.setOutcome(urlWithFragment);
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `outcome` of `HtmlOutcomeTargetLink` (the `<h:link>`) only takes navigation case outcomes, not URLs. The navigation case outcomes do not support URL fragments. Those needs to be set as a separate `fragment` attribute.

```
link.setFragment("top");
```

#### See also:

- [`<h:link>` tag documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/link.html)

---

**Update**: wait, there's no setter for that on the [`UIOutcomeTarget`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIOutcomeTarget.html) parent class. I suspect an oversight in the generated code (funnily it's mentioned [here in Mojarra snapshot docs](http://javaserverfaces-spec-public.java.net/nonav/snapshots/jsf-spec-2.0-20090304/javadocs/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlOutcomeTargetLink.html) and [here in a MyFaces testcase](http://myfaces.apache.org/core20/myfaces-impl/xref-test/org/apache/myfaces/renderkit/html/HtmlLinkRendererTest.html)). You should be able to set it directly on the attribute map:

```
link.getAttributes().put("fragment", "top");
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is no setFragment defined for HtmlOutcomeTargetLink

Comment: Hmm, that look like an oversight. Try `getAttributes().put("fragment", "top")` instead.

Comment: works! thank you very much, your my stackoverflow jsf hero ;-)

Comment: How to accomplish this with a commandbutton action? cannot put it in the navigation rules, as it looks for a view id

Comment: Either change the URL of the generated `<form action>` using a custom `ViewHandler`, or send a redirect to the desired URL in action method.

Comment: how to accomplish the latter? tried returning "/path/to/view.xhtml#top" in the action method and adding a "<redirect />" in the faces config but that doesnt work

Comment: `ExternalContext#redirect()`.