# JSF navigating to named anchor

Tags: jsf, navigation

I have a JSF2 form which is not near the top of the page, the form has a named anchor in the heading:

```
<h2><a name="contact_form">Contact Us</a></h2>
```

The form consists of user-side validation, for example:

```
<f:validateLength for="message" minimum="10"/>
<f:validateRegex for="email" pattern="#{regex['email']}" />
```

When the validation fails, the user is redirected to the top of the page, however the error messages are shown in the form. When the form passes validation, the request is processed in the ManagedBean and a success message is shown in the form, I am returning the string:

```
public String sendMessage () {
    // process request ...

    return "#contact_form";
}
```

This code results in the warning:

```
WARNING: JSF1090: Navigation case not resolved for component j_idt83.
```

1. I would prefer for the validation to fail and redirect to the named anchor.
2. I would prefer for successful processing of the form to redirect to the named anchor.

**Footnote:** This form is inserted by a `ui:include` statement on every page of the site, I do not necessarily know the url that the form is on.

Comment: Not sure of the answer but one observation - `<a name="">` is not supported in html 5. Just use an id on your h2 for that. `<h2 id="contact_form">Contact us</h2>` will work just fine with a fragment href such as `href='#contact_form'`

Answer (score 0):

I don;t think you can return a fragment as a navigation outcome, at least not without writing a custom NavigationHandler class. (see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676481/how-to-add-url-fragment-htmloutcometargetlink), particularly the comments on the accepted answer)

In our application we got round this using a bit of jquery in our master page template that in the document.ready() function selects any element that has an id that ends with "scroll_to_anchor" and if found, sets the window location to the first element that has that id. I'm not able to access my codebase right now but I remember it was quite straightforward and if you're interested in my solution I can post the code tomorrow when I'm in the office.